# Responsive Select Menu Target _blank

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

Hi i have a working responsive select menu, i would like to be able to make just one of the links target _blank

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value;">

    <option value="" selected="selected">Navigation</option> 
    <option value="#">Home</option> 
    <option value="lessons/">Lessons</option> 
    <option value="locations/">Locations</option> 
    <option value="accomodation/">Accommodation</option> 
    <option value="holidays/">Holidays</option> 
    <option value="shop/">Shop</option> 
    <option value="contact/">Contact</option> 
    <option value="kite-jobs/">Jobs</option> 

</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select>

    <option value="" selected="selected">Navigation</option> 
    <option value="#">Home</option> 
    <option value="lessons/">Lessons</option> 
    <option value="locations/">Locations</option> 
    <option value="accomodation/">Accommodation</option> 
    <option value="holidays/">Holidays</option> 
    <option value="shop/">Shop</option> 
    <option value="contact/">Contact</option> 
    <option value="kite-jobs/">Jobs</option> 

</select>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function() {  
      var url = this.value;  
      if(url == 'shop/' ){            // or whatever
        window.open(url, '_blank');
      }else{
        window.location.href = url;
      }    
    });
});
```

Comment: This was very close to working, but chrome is blocking the new window as a pop up, and the new window link did not work in safari mobile.

Comment: How can we add a country flag to these options?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open()` in the case you want:

```
<select onchange="if (this.value === 'accomodation') window.open(this.value, '_blank') else if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value;">
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work, i want the use this function on the Shop link it has to open to a cnamed url i.e. http://shop.website.com